# Uwp Autosuggestbox OrderBy Displaymemberpath

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, sql-order-by, textchanged

I have a behavior for my autosuggestbox where I have to order all the suggested list items by ascending order, and this behavior will is being applied to 1 common style of AutoSuggestBox across whole app. When I try ordering simply with the object itself it works fine as the items are just a list of strings. But when the items are a list of objects, and I want to sort with 1 specific property, then it is not working for me. I am using DisplayMemberPath to tell it which property it should look for. Below is the code I tried with :

### Behavior

```
public class AutoSuggestSortBehavior : IBehavior
{
    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject) => ((AutoSuggestBox) associatedObject).TextChanged += AutoSuggestSortBehavior_TextChanged;

    private void AutoSuggestSortBehavior_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var autoSuggestBox = sender;
        if(autoSuggestBox?.Items?.Count > 0 && args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sender.Text))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(autoSuggestBox.DisplayMemberPath))
            {
                autoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = autoSuggestBox.Items.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(autoSuggestBox.DisplayMemberPath).Name).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                autoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = autoSuggestBox.Items.ToList().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            }
        }            
    }
    public void Detach(DependencyObject associatedObject) => ((AutoSuggestBox) associatedObject).TextChanged -= AutoSuggestSortBehavior_TextChanged;
}
```

### Xaml

```
<AutoSuggestBox
    Header="AutoSuggest"
    QueryIcon="Find"
    Text="With text, header and icon"
    TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged" />
<AutoSuggestBox
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    Header="AutoSuggest2"
    QueryIcon="Find"
    Text="With text, header and icon"
    TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged2" />
```

### TextChanged events

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var abcc = new List<string>();
        abcc.Add("xyz");
        abcc.Add("321");
        abcc.Add("123");
        abcc.Add("lopmjk");
        abcc.Add("acb");
        sender.ItemsSource = abcc;
    }

    private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged2(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var persons = new List<Person>();
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "xyz", count = 1 });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "321", count = 2 });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "123", count = 3 });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "lopmjk", count = 4 });
        persons.Add(new Person { Name = "acb", count = 5 });
        sender.ItemsSource = persons;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution with a little experiment, we can use the GetValue() method with passing in the object itself and then it works as expected :

```
autoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = autoSuggestBox.Items.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(autoSuggestBox.DisplayMemberPath).GetValue(x)).ToList();
```